# The response was already committed by the time we tried to set the outgoing cookie for the flash. Any values stored to the flash will not be available

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, flash-scope

I have one view scoped JSF managed bean. In the action listener method of `<p:commandButton>` in this managed bean, I'm redirecting to another page as follows.

```
public void register() {
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    Flash flash = context.getFlash();
    flash.setKeepMessages(true);
    flash.put("emailId", emailId);
    context.redirect(((HttpServletRequest) context.getRequest()).getContextPath()+"/page.jsf");
}
```

`page.jsf` is bound to a request scoped bean in which I'm receiving the email address stored in a flash scope as follows.

```
<ui:define name="metaData">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{requestScopedBean.init}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

```
public void init() {
    String emailId = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("emailId");
    System.out.println("emailId = "+emailId);
}
```

The email address is unavailable in the target bean. The email address in the target bean is required just to show the user who has registered to indicate that a message has been sent to that address so that the email address can be verified.

It produces the following warning on the server terminal.

> WARNING:   JSF1095: The response was already committed by the time we
>   tried to set the outgoing cookie for the flash.  Any values stored to
>   the flash will not be available on the next request.

Why does this happen? My Mojarra version is 2.2.7